# Projectile in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in which user can move a sphere through x-axis and can make a projectile through y-axis while swiping that sphere.I know how to move the object throughout x-axis but have no idea about making a projectile while swiping that object,any kind of help will be greatly appreciated..here's my code so far....

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: I want to make a parabolic projection through y-axis while swiping that sphere.

Comment: Parabolic movement can be made by physics using gravity and linear drag. Just use `rigidbody.AddForce()` on swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You like move the projectile if it is in the sphere, is correct?

In this case if you detect a circle/projectile intersection you can add the Xspeed of the circle to the projectile.

```
//PROJECTILE OBJECT
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
{
     xSpeed = xSpeed + other.gameObject.xSpeed;
}
```

For you second question you need create a script and attach this script to a scene element, I use OnMouseDown event but you can use your event.

```
//CREATOR OBJECT
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class createProjectile : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject projectile;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Instantiate(projectile);
    }
}
```

And you need assign the GameObject projectile in the Unity inspector:
[UnityInspectorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptPRO.png)

Comment: Thank you,but can you please tell me how can I create the projectile while swiping the sphere?

Comment: What is the event that will create your projectile ?

Comment: Ok, I add your second question in the answer. Good luck with your game

Comment: Thank you so much.